# Can I make my wallpaper a fully functioning terminal on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, desktop-background

I would like to turn my wallpaper into a fully functioning terminal so I don't have to open one when I start my computer. Is there any way I could do this? By wallpaper, I mean background of course.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this solution will suit you, but you could install a drop-down terminal. I personally use [Guake](http://guake-project.org/) (`sudo apt-get install guake`). If you configure the Guake terminal to take up the whole screen, you have something close to* what you want. If you add the toggle command `guake-toggle` to the startup applications (put it after starting up Guake itself), following the instructions in [Crighton's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1285474/1101910), the terminal should not only start up in the background but also appear on startup.

*I know it's not 100% what you asked, but I thought I'd give my 2 cents on it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "background" but you can auto start applications as per https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en

- on 20.04 at the bottom of the side dock click the  9 dot grid and type "startup" in the search box in the middle of the screen for the application you want to use (Startup Applications) and then add "terminal" from the pick list.
  so I do this too - I have a terminal start on  one of my computers as I always use it to remote into my server - is this the functionality you are looking for?